# Add a series of instances of a Class to ArrayList variable

Tags: arraylist, multiple-instances

This code seems to match pretty close to an example I found on online, but its not right, and I can't find an example that matches what I'm trying to do. Maybe I just don't have the parameters and fields setup correctly; or maybe my approach is wrong.

```
package vibrationSimulator;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import sineWaveAnimation.SineDisplay;
import audioOutput.JFrame_sliderSine;

public class VibrationSimulator {

    private static List<MachineParameters> machineParameterArray;
    private static int ia;
    private static MachineParameters machineParameter_1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start();
    }

    public static void Start() {
        ArrayList<MachineParameters> machineParameterArray = new ArrayList<MachineParameters>();
        MachineParameters machineParameter_1 = new MachineParameters();
        machineParameter_1.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void Process() {
        // machineParameterArray.add(machineParameter_1);
        if (MachineParameters.isGoDone()) {
            // machineParameterArray[ia] = machineParameter_1;
            MachineParameters machineParameter_1 = new MachineParameters();
            machineParameter_1.frame.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            StartAnimations();
        }
    }
```

I have  MachineParameters Class whith a simple GUI for inputting the values. Start creates the first instance of MachineParameters and Process is supposed to add that instance to the ArrayList when it is called from the MachineParameter Class. Process creates another instance if GoDone is true or starts and animation if false. The ArrayList will be used to set the parameters for the animation. The true/false is set by the Submit or Done buttons on the GUI.

When I add the Remmed out line:
// machineParameterArray.add(machineParameter_1);
machineParameters_1 doesn't refer to the instance.

Also, all instances have the same name; I'm not sure how to increment a variable name - doesn't seem correct.

Laugh at me if you want, but I will get this right eventually; and then I'll know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ArrayList from the constructor. Apparently it creates a local variable instead of an instance.

So:
machineParameterArray = new ArrayList();